# How to AutoFill/Populate Radio-Button-Based Forms

Tags: javascript

I'm mostly a coding noob, but I was wondering if anybody can get me started on being able to autofill radio buttons with JS.

I was able to find this bit of code:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar W=%5B%5D,V=Math.random,U=Math.floor,T,S,R,Q,P='password',O=U(V()*9e6),N=O+'@example.com';function M(L,H)%7Btry%7BH=L.document.getElementsByTagName(H)%7Dcatch(e)%7BH=%5B%5D%7Dfor(i=0;i<H.length;i++)%7BT=H%5Bi%5D;if(T.readOnly%7C%7CT.disabled)continue;S=T.name;R=T.type;Q=T.value;if('checkbox'==R)T.checked=V()>.5;if(P==R)Q=O;if('text'==R)%7BQ=U(V()*9e6);if(S.match(/mail/i))Q=N%7DT.value=Q;if('radio'==R)%7Bif(!++W%5BS%5D)W%5BS%5D=1;T.checked=V()<(1/W%5BS%5D)%7Dif(R.match(/%5Eselect/))T.selectedIndex=V()*(T.options.length-1)+1%7Dif(T)try%7BT.focus()%7Dcatch(e)%7B%7D%7Dfunction G(L)%7BM(L,P);M(L,'select');M(L,'input');for(var i=0;i<L.frames.length;i++)%7BG(L.frames%5Bi%5D)%7D%7DG(window)%7D());void(0)
```

This code only autopopulates randomly and doesn't appear to bubble on sites like surveymonkey and qualtrics. Personally, I'd like to be able to autofill 5-question radio buttons/selections to the 4th value every time - I want the 4th radio button selected per question, on pages with multiple questions, too. Since for most 5-choice answers the 4th choice has the highest percentage of being correct, I figure this will save some time here and there.

If there is any bits of code or resources I can be directed to, that would be awesome! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that checks every 4th radio in groups of 5.

```
<input type = 'radio' name = 'one' value = '1' />1<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'one' value = '2' />2<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'one' value = '3' />3<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'one' value = '4' />4<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'one' value = '5' />5<br />
<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'two' value = '1' />1<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'two' value = '2' />2<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'two' value = '3' />3<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'two' value = '4' />4<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'two' value = '5' />5<br />
<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'three' value = '1' />1<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'three' value = '2' />2<br />
<input type = 'radio' name = 'three' value = '3' />3<br />
<script>
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  var nameCount = {};
  for (var i = 0, name; i < radios.length; i++) {
    name = radios[i].name;
    if (!(name in nameCount)) nameCount[name] = 0;
    nameCount[name]++;
  }
  var radioToCheck;
  for (name in nameCount) {
    if (nameCount[name] === 5) {
      radioToCheck = document.getElementsByName(name)[3];
      radioToCheck.checked = true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but that is that code that is applicable to browsers and not just page pages? The code I cited can be used within a google bookmark, for instance, to execute that JS code on survey websites. Your code doesn't appear to be suited for that, otherwise I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Here is a version you can put in a bookmark: https://gist.github.com/calebsander/886f03a594b69ebc93646c2cf96de2bb

Answer (score 0):

Qualtrics has an easy way to do this without writing any code.  Click on the cog next to the question and select "Add Default Choices...".

The problem with doing this on a global basis with a script is not all multiple choice questions with 5 answer options are scales. A script probably couldn't tell the difference.

Also, from a data quality perspective, you are highly biasing all the answers.  A lot of respondents won't even bother to read the question if you have pre-selected the answer for them. Then, even if they do read it, it is likely they won't change it.